# AvCam-ios switch from rear to front cameras is very slow,how can i fix this?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, ios-camera

///before toggle,I exactly sure isRunning == true

```
   func toggleCamera(){
        let first:TimeInterval = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
        let currentVideoDevice = self.videoInput.device
        ///////////////begin to switch
        self.captureSession.beginConfiguration()
        self.captureSession.removeInput(self.videoInput)
        if self.cameraDeviceType == .back {
            self.cameraDeviceType = .front
            self.inputCamera = self.frontDevice
        }else{
            self.cameraDeviceType = .back
            self.inputCamera = self.backDevice
        }
        do {
            self.videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device:self.inputCamera)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        if self.captureSession.canAddInput(self.videoInput) {
            NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .AVCaptureDeviceSubjectAreaDidChange, object: currentVideoDevice)
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.subjectAreaDidChange), name: .AVCaptureDeviceSubjectAreaDidChange, object: self.videoInput.device)

            self.captureSession.addInput(self.videoInput)
        } else {
            self.captureSession.addInput(self.videoInput)
        }
        self.captureSession.commitConfiguration()
        if let connection = self.videoOutput?.connection(withMediaType: "video") {
            if connection.isVideoStabilizationSupported {
                connection.preferredVideoStabilizationMode = .auto
            }
            connection.isEnabled = false
            connection.isEnabled = true
        }
        let second:TimeInterval = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
        print("turnAroundInnerCost:",second-first)
    }
```

////log:  turnAroundInnerCost: 0.431715965270996
///the running time is soon,but the interface switch is slow,about 5s

Answer (score 1):

So, every toggle you recreate your camera, reconfigure devices, enable/disable connection, etc. Try to move your camera configuration logic to other function and call it once for example in viewDidLoad().

Switching between cameras can be:

```
     func switchToFrontCamera() throws {
            guard let inputs = captureSession.inputs as? [AVCaptureInput], let rearCameraInput = self.rearCameraInput, inputs.contains(rearCameraInput),
                let frontCamera = self.frontCamera else { throw CameraError.invalidOperation }

            self.frontCameraInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: frontCamera)

            captureSession.removeInput(rearCameraInput)

            if captureSession.canAddInput(self.frontCameraInput) {
                captureSession.addInput(self.frontCameraInput)

                self.currentCameraPosition = .front
            }

            else {
                throw CameraError.invalidOperation
            }
        }

     func switchToRearCamera() throws {
            guard let inputs = captureSession.inputs as? [AVCaptureInput], let frontCameraInput = self.frontCameraInput, inputs.contains(frontCameraInput),
                let rearCamera = self.rearCamera else { throw CameraError.invalidOperation }

            self.rearCameraInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: rearCamera)

            captureSession.removeInput(frontCameraInput)

            if captureSession.canAddInput(self.rearCameraInput) {
                captureSession.addInput(self.rearCameraInput)

                self.currentCameraPosition = .rear
            }

            else { throw CameraError.invalidOperation }
        }
```

and then you can call

```
  switch currentCameraPosition {
    case .front:
        try switchToRearCamera()

    case .rear:
        try switchToFrontCamera()
  }
```

Comment: I post my now logic below

Answer (score 0):

//create captureSession once in viewDid(),but this func was running still slow when i changed the camera from rear to front

```
let frontDevice = AVCaptureDevice.devices(withMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo).map { $0 as! AVCaptureDevice }.filter { $0.position == .front}.first!

let backDevice = AVCaptureDevice.devices(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo).map { $0 as! AVCaptureDevice }.filter { $0.position == .back}
    .first!

public func turnAroundCamera() {
    sessionQueue.async {
        let first:TimeInterval = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
        let oldVedioInput = self.videoInput

        //self.captureSession.beginConfiguration()

        self.captureSession.removeInput(self.videoInput)
        if self.cameraDeviceType == .back {
            self.cameraDeviceType = .front
            self.inputCamera = self.frontDevice
        }else{
            self.cameraDeviceType = .back
            self.inputCamera = self.backDevice
        }
        do {
            self.videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device:self.inputCamera)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

        if self.captureSession.canAddInput(self.videoInput) {
            self.captureSession.addInput(self.videoInput)
        }else{
            self.captureSession.addInput(oldVedioInput)
        }
        //self.captureSession.commitConfiguration()

        let second:TimeInterval = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
        print("turnAroundInnerCost:",second-first)
    }
}
```

More info,Log turnAroundInnerCost: 0.245857000350952

Actually the function turnAroundCamera() run fast when i called it,but the captureOutput() run slow (about 5s) behind the function turnAroundCamera() end.It's time expensive especially when i try to turn around the camera from rear to front .So what i try to do (enable/disable) is to flush the session which hope to flush the captureOutput.....